# What Encoder choose when using StreamReader

Tags: c#-3.0

I'm trying to fix a piece of code for a task that runs daily, and uses a StreamReader with no encoder defined to read a file that contains english and french text. So I'm getting a character � instead when french accents are found.

If I set Encoding.Default the problem is fixed, but [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx) they don't recommend using it. So I'd like to know what would be the right approach.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The recommendation is to avoid text files that are not encoded in Unicode.  Just send them back, you don't want them.

Comment: try using Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") or better you can send back if you dont want to handle the data.

Comment: Thank you, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") did it. After asking the company who send us those daily files found that the actual encoding the external source uses was that one.